# How to get rid of this NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a simple calculator app using Android Studio. 
It shows error at these lines,

```
      compute();
      value2 = Double.parseDouble(display.getText().toString());
```

Below is my android code:

```
 sum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            compute();
            act = ADD;
            display.setText(String.valueOf(value1) + "+");
          //  display.setText(display.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(value2));
           // display.setText(null);
        }
    });
```

when equal is pressed,

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            compute();
            //act = EQU;
            //result.setText(display.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(value2) +  "=" + String.valueOf(value1));
           // result.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
         //   result.setText(display.getText().toString()+String.valueOf(value1));
         //   result.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
           //display.setText(null);
            result.setText(String.valueOf(result_num));
        }
    });

}
```

Here doing the calculation part

```
    public void compute(){
        if(!Double.isNaN(value1)){
            value2 = Double.parseDouble(display.getText().toString());

            switch (act){
                case ADD:
                    result_num = value1 + value2;
                    //break;
                case SUB:
                    result_num = value1 - value2;
                    break;
                case MUL:
                    value1 = value1 * value2;
                    break;
                case DIV:
                    value1 = value1 / value2;
                    break;
               /* case EQU:
                    break;*/
            }
        }
        else{
            value1 = Double.parseDouble(display.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, I couldn't proceed next step. Why this is not working?

Comment: in which line or chunk of code you got an error ?

Comment: Can you add your details stack trace?

Comment: where is value1 ?

Comment: `display.getText().toString()` does not return a String that can be parsed into a double. Debug or print it out to find out its value right before doing the `parseDouble`

Answer (score 3):

If you are parsing values like space, alphanumeric, special character you will get ***NumberFormatException*** . In your case you are concatenating **"+"** in onClick of sum at this line `display.setText(String.valueOf(value1) + "+");` and you are parsing that value here `value2 = Double.parseDouble(display.getText().toString());` and here `value1 = Double.parseDouble(display.getText().toString());` in *compute()* method which will definitely cause NumberFormatException. So, split the value based on "+" and parse it.

Answer (score 2):

[parseDouble](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Double#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) can throw [NumberFormatException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) and [NullPointerException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) so you have to surround parseDouble with try/catch every time you are calling it or you have the risk to crash. Here is

```
/**
     * Returns a new {@code double} initialized to the value
     * represented by the specified {@code String}, as performed
     * by the {@code valueOf} method of class
     * {@code Double}.
     *
     * @param  s   the string to be parsed.
     * @return the {@code double} value represented by the string
     *         argument.
     * @throws NullPointerException  if the string is null
     * @throws NumberFormatException if the string does not contain
     *         a parsable {@code double}.
     * @see    java.lang.Double#valueOf(String)
     */
    public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
        return FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(s);
    }
```

so all of your parseDoubles should look like this (also you should trim your string to prevent passing spaces to parseDouble):

```
    try{
        value2 = Double.parseDouble(display.getText().toString().trim());
    }catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException ex){
        //set some value in case of exceptions
        //, for example, value2=0 or show a message to user cause his input is not valid
    }
```

Comment: I think you should trim() after toString()

Answer (score 0):

Check what display.getText().toString() is returning. It should not return alphanumeric string or string with special characters. It should return a numeric string i.e string with numbers only otherwise you will get NumberFormatException.